# Create New Folder in Android Studio is empty (nothing here)

Tags: android-studio

## Resume:

Normally in Android Studio when you right click on a SRC directory, the menu NEW> FOLDER> have many options like: AIDLS Folder, Assets, INI, JAVA, etc:

New>Folder>Option example

[image]

My is empty (see last image bellow).

## Theory:

I have created two product flavors in my in my Build.Gradle:

```
flavorDimensions "version"
productFlavors {
    free {
        applicationId "com.xxxx.yyyy.free"
        versionName "1.0-free"
        buildConfigField "boolean", "PAID_VERSION", "false"

        dimension "version"
        applicationIdSuffix ".free"
        versionNameSuffix "-free"
    }

    full {
        applicationId "com.xxxx.yyyy.paid"
        versionName "1.0-full"
        buildConfigField "boolean", "PAID_VERSION", "true"

        dimension "version"
        applicationIdSuffix ".full"
        versionNameSuffix "-full"
    }
}
```

When you create a new product flavor, Android Studio doesn't create the source set directories for you, but it does give you a few options to help you. For example, to create just the java/ directory for your "debug" or "release" build:

Open the Project pane and select the Project view from the drop-down menu at the top of the pane.
Navigate to MyProject/app/src/.
Right-click the src directory and select New > Folder > Java Folder.
From the drop-down menu next to Target Source Set, select debug or release.
Click Finish.Android Studio creates a source set directory for your debug build type, and then creates the java/ directory inside it.

(Ref. https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants?utm_source=android-studio#product-flavors)

## Problem:

As you can see in the following image, my Folder options is empty. Can anybody explain me why?

[image]

Comment: Please avoid using third party image hosting services. These have in the past [presented several issues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279664/332043), and there is a perfectly viable on-site option through `stack.imgur.com` (press the image button while editing, or copy an image and paste it, again, while editing).

Comment: Sorry Zoe, its my mistake!. Only now I have realized that it is on the second screen of the guided mode and not in the first screen (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55994663/suggestion-include-the-add-image-button-on-the-first-page-of-guided-mode-to-avo). Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: The folder options came back after restarting Android Studio and Rebuild the Project. Can’t simulate back the case and the real reason it’s unknown to me or it’s an Android Studio 3.2.1 bug.